# Unable to add reference to C++ DLL in C# project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, cmake, dll

I have created a C++ DLL using CMake. The C++ project consisting of the following files:

- src/setup.cpp
- src/setup.h
- CMakeLists.txt

setup.cpp is as follows:

```
#include "setup.h"

int myFunction() {
    return 42;
}
```

setup.h is as follows:

```
#ifndef SETUP_DLL
#define SETUP_DLL

int myFunction();

#endif
```

CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Define the project and supported versions
project(MyLibrary VERSION 1.0.0)

# Add options for compiling the library
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# Add the library sources
add_library(MyLibrary SHARED src/setup.h src/setup.cpp)

# Specify the directory to search for headers
target_include_directories(MyLibrary PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

# Specify the output name
set_target_properties(MyLibrary PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "MyLibrary_${PROJECT_VERSION}")

# Specify the output path
set_target_properties(MyLibrary PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")
```

I am now trying to import this DLL into a C# project. To do this, I right-click on the project in Visual Studio 2019, choose "Add", "Reference", "Browse", and then select the DLL file I created. However, I get the error message `Could not add reference to 'Path\to\file.dll'. Make sure the file is accessible and that the assembly or COM component is valid.`

What could be causing this error? How can I successfully add the reference to the C++ DLL in my C# project?

Comment: The error message tells you the problem: it needs to be an assembly, unless your C++ DLL is a C++/CLI assembly then you'll need to P/Invoke the exported C functions you wish to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I generate an assembly?

Comment: There is no need for cli/assembly... Do not add as reference ... Just use pinvoke(internet search as already asked multiple times) (but first in c you need to export your function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header adds extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) :

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int myFunction();
```

[P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke): C# call C++ dll:

```
[DllImport("XX\\Temp\\Debug\\MyLibrary_1.0.0.dll")]
private static extern  int myFunction();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   myFunction();
}
```